# How to configure CORS policy in Cloud Foundry Staticfile Buildpack to add missing 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: cors, cloud-foundry, static-files

When I try to access a JavaScript file hosted on Cloud Foundry using the [Staticfile Buildpack](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/staticfile/index.html), my browser refuses to load it and displays an error message in the console:

> Access to script at ‘…’ from origin ‘…’ has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

How do I configure cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) in the Cloud Foundry Staticfile Buildpack?

Answer (score 7):

### To set up CORS with the Staticfile Buildpack:

1. Create a file named `Staticfile` with the following contents:

   ```
    root: public
    location_include: includes/*.conf
   ```
2. Ensure that the files you want your app to serve are located in the `public` folder.
3. Create the file `nginx/conf/includes/headers.conf` (with its parent folders) with the following contents:

   ```
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
   ```

That's it! After your next `cf push`, the CORS header will be set.

For more clarity, see also the official code sample [`include_headers_public`](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack/tree/master/fixtures/include_headers_public).

### Explanation

As of the [Staticfile Buildpack documentation](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/staticfile/index.html#staticfile-detection):

> If you create a file named `Staticfile` and locate it in the build directory of your app, Cloud Foundry automatically uses the Staticfile buildpack when you push your app.

(It means you don't need to specify the `staticfile_buildpack` in your `manifest.yml`)

Then follow the instructions under [`Custom Location`](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/staticfile/index.html#custom-location).

> Custom Location allows you to specify custom location definitions with additional directives.

> To customize the location block of the NGINX configuration file, follow the steps below.

> 1. Set an alternative `root` directory. The `location_include` property only works in conjunction with an alternative `root`.

> 2. Create a file with location-scoped NGINX directives. See the following example, which causes visitors of your site to receive the `X-MySiteName` HTTP header:
>
>    - File: `nginx/conf/includes/custom_header.conf`
>    - Content: `add_header X-MySiteName BestSiteEver;`

> 3. Set the `location_include` variable in your **Staticfile** to the path of the file from the previous step. This path is relative to `nginx/conf`.
>
>    Example:
>
>    ```
>     root: public
>     location_include: includes/*.conf
>    ```

Comment: Looks like there is typo in your answer at the end of Location there is additional '%' which does not make it work. Rather it should be just 'location_include: includes/*.conf'. This works. I was looking exactly for this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A bit of history - This got implemented to the Static Build Pack via this story - https://www.pivotaltracker.com/n/projects/1042066/stories/136370663

A similar issue was raised against the BuildPack team - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack/issues/89

Refer to the below sample App on how to configure any additional custom headers - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack/tree/master/fixtures/include_headers_public

You can then additionally add CORS specific response headers as well (allowed hosts & allowed methods)