# How to add header config using staticfile_buildpack for Angular app?

Tags: angular, nginx, cloud-foundry, pcfdev

I created a build using `ng build --prod`. It created a `dist/AppName` folder and inside it I have my manifest.yml and Staticfile. When I do `cf push` inside `dist/AppName` everything is working fine but I wanted to add a header config of `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*'` (nginx config) but I don't know how to do it in Staticfile. I got some lead like using `location_include` but the documentation about it is kinda confusing. Could someone help or guide me on how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure CORS policy in Cloud Foundry Staticfile Buildpack to add missing 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58408784/how-to-configure-cors-policy-in-cloud-foundry-staticfile-buildpack-to-add-missin)

Comment: I saw same information in Pivotal which is kinda confusing to follow. I managed to solve my problem by going over to the staticfile_buildpack fixtures in github and saw a sample there. Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue by looking at the sameple staticfile-buildpack  [fixtures on github](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack/tree/master/fixtures).
When I do `ng build --prod` Angular put the compiled code in `dist/AppName`. Inside `dist` folder I put the `manifest.yml`, `Staticfile` and added a new folder `nginx/conf/includes`. The new folder is where I put my headers.conf, which contains the add_header nginx directive.

so `dist` has the following files and folders

```
dist
  |_ AppName/
  |_ nginx/
  |   |_ conf
  |       |_ includes
  |           |_ headers.conf 
  |_ manifest.yml
  |_ Staticfile
```

Staticfile has the following content:

```
pushstate: enabled
root: AppName
location_include: includes/*.conf
```

manifest.yml:

```
---
applications:
- name: appname-dev
  memory: 512M
  disk_quota: 1024M
  instances: 1
  timeout: 90
  buildpack: staticfile_buildpack
```

I did the `cf push` inside `dist` folder